# Remoting Automation of MS Office on the server

Tags: c#, wcf, interop, ms-office, .net-remoting

I'm warning you, that yhis question will seems to be very strange for a lot of people:) But I have to post it because my project manager is teeling me that a technical solution exist, even if for me it doesn't.

What we have:

- A Windows 7 Console Application with no UI, with our C# application running and no Office and Interop on it
- a Windows 2012 server, with Ms Office 2010 + Interop installed on it (also with IIS and .NET of course)

What my PM want (and I told him it is not possible) :

- From my C# client application
- Automate "Ms office" installed on the server
- Automate means "Save" or "print" a doc file to a network printer.
- Of course the Ms office process had to run on the server

This kind of solution of "remote Ms Office automation is possible" seems to be impossible for me. But maybe I am wrong, it can be possiblbe using DCOM, WCF, or something else?

Anyone can confirm I am right please ;)

Comment: To clarify, what he wants you to do is basically run the version of Office that's installed on the remote server within your application, so the client can perform all functions?  Or just select documents to be be printed and print them through Office installed on the remote server?

Comment: It certainly is possible, but it is not easy. However, a solution would be too complex to post as an answer here. You basically need to create a WCF or Web service that prints the documents and that gets called by your client application.

Comment: @Taegost , that it, i want to perform action (printing, saving docuiment) from my client application, without having Ms office installed on my client. A kind of remote use of interop :)

Comment: @DirkVollmar The solution of the WS or WCF is the solution i have proposed to him but he told us it was too difficult to maintain (IIS administration, WS declaration....). But for me it is the most reliable !!

"It certainly is possible"... thoses words sounds interesting for me... do you have more detail on its ??

Comment: @sstassin - Which one is it?  Your usage of the word "save" throws a wrench in the gears, because that implies editing in addition to only printing.  If all you need is to select documents and print, yeah a service on the server would be best, but if they want to implement Office in your application, they're better off setting up some Terminal Services or Citrix...

Comment: @Taegost, our first goal is to print (editing or saving  the document can be forgotten in the first times) . For the implement of Citrix or TS Services i am just adding some lines to the original post because it is not so simple :)

Comment: Can you clarify how Office applications are to be used from your app? If you are just sending files to a printer then I don't think Office automation is required at all - you just need to submit files to the printer queue using .NET, Win32 or something else.  Also keep this in mind: "Considerations for server-side Automation of Office": https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

Comment: @EricLegault , yes we know that "Considerations for server-side Automation of Office" is a bad thing, but at the moment we did not find a third party compenent that have a really accurate rendering of an existing word document. What we are try to to is, on our client application (with no ui, so it can be also considerated like web server) launch the print/conversion to pdf of an existing doc using the Ms Word installed on ou server, without ms word installed on the client workstation. This is why i am talking of a "remote office automation".

Comment: @EricLegault : what do you mean by 'If you are just sending files to a printer then I don't think Office automation is required at all' . Do you mean it is possible to print an existing word document without Word on the computer ??? And also with no other third party .net compenent like Aspose or Synchfusion ??  If you have an example or a link i will be interested but i don't think this is possible.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to mention Aspose. Forget what I said about printing - an associated application for the file of course needs to exist to render it to the queue. You can install the free Word Viewer I suppose. Otherwise, you do need Word or a third-party converter (I was going to mention Aspose for the server-side) for the PDF conversion. Ideally your client needs a budget for proper software!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already learned from the comments, automating the desktop version of any of the Office applications is bad for several reasons. The details can be found in the Knowledge base article KB257757 [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757). The main take away from that article is:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

But as you are still insisting, consider the following example as a very simple, naive, not to be used near production proof-of-concept that enables you to quickly run into all problems mentioned in the KB article.

In a fresh solution create a WCF Service application and a Console Application. In the WCF application add the following interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPrintService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Print(Stream wordDoc);
}
```

and have a service implement that. Make sure to add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` that you can find in the COM tab of the Add Reference dialog.

```
public class PrintService : IPrintService
{
    public string Print(Stream wordDocStream)
    {
        // copy our stream to a local file
        var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        using(var file = File.Create(tempFile))
        {
            wordDocStream.CopyTo(file);
        }

        // start word
        var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        // setup printer
        wordApp.ActivePrinter = "Canon LBP3010/LBP3018/LBP3050";
        // open, collect data, print and close
        var doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(tempFile);
        doc.PrintOut();
        var res = doc.Words.Count;
        doc.Close(false);

        // quit word
        wordApp.Quit(false);
        // delete temp file
        File.Delete(tempFile);
        return String.Format("{0} words", res);
    }
}
```

You can see here a barebone solution to print a document that is sent as a stream to the Service. The service copies the stream to a file, starts Word, Opens the file, prints the document, get some data from the document and tears down and cleans up hen finished.

The client is straight forward:

```
using(var client = new PrintService.PrintServiceClient())
{
    using(var file = File.Open(@"small.docx", FileMode.Open))
    {
        var response = client.Print(file);
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
```

This is technically all there is that is needed to print a Word document from a service. This runs without much problems on the dev server. If you run this on IIS you'll probably have to make sure that the account used as an identity in the AppPool is a "user" that can start Word, is allowed to access the printers etc. I already ran into one known issue: I used the XPS Print driver which caused a dialog to popup. That is something you can't have on a server and there is no real way to prevent or detect that.

Remember that this service interface only allows for a stream to be sent. If you want to add extra data you'll have to use a message contract as is explained on msdn in [Large Data and Streaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx). Your contract would have to look like this in that case:

```
[MessageContract]
public class UploadStreamMessage
{
   [MessageHeader]
   public string appRef;
   [MessageBodyMember]
   public Stream data;
}
```

If you run all this, (stress)test, consider deployment and install I'm sure you'll convince anyone that this isn't a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for very detailled answer. Il will try to implement this on our Intranet Web Server. I am aware of all the MS considerations of "not using ms office in Server Mode" but nowadays it is the best way to print complex exisiing document with a very good accuracy.